# Шампіньйон чи печериця?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, іменники

СУМ-11 містить обидва слова

> [Шампіньйон](http://sum.in.ua/s/shampinjjon) Те саме, що печериця 1.
>
> [Печериця](http://sum.in.ua/s/pecherycja) 1. Їстівний гриб родини пластинникових із сірою або
>   білуватою шапинкою на тонкій білій ніжці, який росте на полях, луках,
>   городах, у садках і т. ін.; шампіньйон.

На сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/grubu-ukrayinskoyu-movoyu), наголошують, що правильно лише печериця.

[image] 
Чи потрібно відмовитись від використання слова "шампіньйон" для означення гриба? Чи можна використовувати обидва слова, як взаємозаміні?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Шампіньйон" - це запозичене слово (від фанц. "champignon", що означає гриб (див. [Вікіпедію](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F)).

А от слово "[печериця](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf)" (ЕСУМ, ст 364 ПДФ) за походженням ближче до нашої мови. Хоч немає однозначної версії як воно з'явилося (чи то від слова "печера", чи то від слова "пекти" чи навіть від словосполучення "печеня турова").

Подивіться назву розділу Мова ДНК нації - "Антисуржик". Отже, якщо ви хочете уникати суржика, то вам слід замінити слово "шампіньйон" на "печериця". Однак саме вживання слова "шампіньйон" не буде помилкою, бо воно все ж воно є в СУМі і біля нього немає ніяких позначок, які б не дозволяли його вживати.

Comment: дякую за відповідь